# Can we keep original author of an item in a impersonated workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

So i have a workflow that have an impersonated step because i need to insert an item into a read only list. I use Sharepoint 2010 workflow plateform. And by copying the item the "created by" column changes to the administrator account. Is it possible to keep the original creator after the copying process?

In my workflow i use "Copy item" method.

I need to do this with OOB solution and i don't see any option for that. Pls help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm..first nice question..What I can think of is to store the Created By field value in one field and show that on the list when the item is created. And hide the Actual Created By field. So this way you can have your original Created By on the list. You can create a workflow which runs on creation and copy this field with Created By

Comment: Haha, I like to believe my developer thinking search for more complicated solutions when all i could do is this haha. I'll wait a bit, maybe there's a way to do this with a hidden option somewhere. After all SharePoint loves to make everything complicated. Thanks for the tip :)